# For a game, what gun names are copyrighted?

Tags: copyright

If a game designer creates a game where the game uses  old soviet weapons and can the game use the name and design picture without copyruight or trademark problems.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I use real life brand names in a computer game?](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/22528/can-i-use-real-life-brand-names-in-a-computer-game)

Answer (score 1):

Short phrases such as names of guns and other products are not protected by copyright at all.  They may be covered by trademark protection. Whether using them in the course of a game wold constitute "use in trade" is doubtful. In aby case the trademark protection would normally be for the market in guns, not games.

Comment: This doesn’t address copyright in the way the guns look

Comment: @Dale M It is common for films, TV shows, and video fames   to show real products of identifiable brands without any attribution, ehile songs, say, get full on-screen credits. My understanding is that appearence copyrights are largely applicable only to creating working copies, and are limited even then. Guns have no more protection than cars do in this respect. If a movie hasd to get permission from the maker of every ordinary object shown, few would be made.

Comment: and that would be addressing it