# Can a game asset violate a trademark or a patent of a product?

Tags: intellectual-property, trademark, patents

Can placing a model of a real life recliner/keyboard/car in my commercial game, violate the trade-dress/trademarks/patents of the manufacturer/brand if it looks and functions like the real thing? Or would it only apply to look and not function or vice versa?

2. Or would that only be the case if the player is able to buy that object in game?
3. Or do all assets in commercial games have to follow same legal obligations and precautions as with real life products?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I use real life brand names in a computer game?](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/22528/can-i-use-real-life-brand-names-in-a-computer-game)

Comment: @BlueDogRanch not quite, I'm asking about 3D trademarks and patents on product designs and functionality, not brand names.

Comment: The linked question nis about brand names, where some very specific trademark rules apply that may not apply, or not as strongly, in the case here described. IMO it is not a duplicate.

Comment: The look of product designs can be granted design patents by the USPTO but to infringe a design patent on a chair one would need to make, sell, offer for sale, import or use an *actual chair*.

Comment: @GeorgeWhite If I understand you correctly you're saying I can make, sell, and use a direct replica game asset of a tesla car/iphone/ps5, without logo and be in the clear? in a large commercial game

Comment: No   - I am saying *patent* rights will not stop you.

Comment: What about trade dress?

Comment: Generally speaking trademark won't stop you either. The copyright and trade dress analysis is more involved.